# LINQ-запрос на выборку данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Мне нужно написать event handler, который удалит всех writer, привязанных к book. Не могу написать LINQ-запрос

```
public class BookBeforeDeletedEventHandler : IEventHandler<BookBeforeDeletedEvent>
{
    private readonly IWriterService _writerService;

    public BookBeforeDeletedEventHandler(ILogger<UserClaimsGeneratedEventHandler> logger, IWriterService writerService)
    {
        _writerService = writerService;
    }

   // handler должен удалять всех writer, привязанных к этой book 
    public Task HandleEvent(BookBeforeDeletedEvent eventMessage)
    {
        // Как правильно написать этот запрос?
        _writerService.DeleteWriters(eventMessage.Book.Writers.Select(e => e.BookId == ???);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Book.cs**

```
[Table("Books")]
public class Book : BaseNetworkEntity
{
    public Book()
    {
        Writers = new List<WriterBook>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WriterBook> Writers { get; set; }

}
```

**Writer.cs**

```
public class Writer: BaseNetworkEntity
{
    public Writer()
    {
        Books = new List<WriterBook>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WriterBook> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**WriterBook**

```
public class WriterBook
{
        public long WriterId { get; set; }
        public long BookId { get; set; }

        public virtual Writer Writer { get; set; }
        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `_writerService.DeleteWriters` что принимает в качестве аргумента?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц `void DeleteWriters(IEnumerable<Writer> writers);`

Comment: почему не просто `_writerService.DeleteWriters(eventMessage.Book.Writers;`?

Comment: `_writerService.DeleteWriters(eventMessage.Book.Writers.Select(e => e.Writer).ToList();`

Comment: @tym32167 `eventMessage.Book.Writers` - тип `ICollection<WriterBook>`, а надо `IEnumerable<Writer>`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а, да, недоглядел эти названия полей/типов

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Подскажите, как работает эта запись `Select(e => e.Writer)`? Я думал, мне нужно сравнивать id книги с id автора. Добавил картинку, как я это понимаю

Comment: `select` ходит по всей коллекции и возвращает то что внутри (например свойство уже имеющейся коллекции ил новую). Чтобы возвратить новую надо так: `.Select(e => new {//TODO})` . если сравнить это вам к `where`